# Get range of numbers from the sorted array

Tags: javascript, math

There is a sorted array with numbers, for example:

```js
const array = [100, 400, 700, 1000, 1300, 1600]
```

There is a function that takes two arguments as input:

```js
function foobar(min, max) {}
```

The function should return the numbers from the array, starting with the first value that is `>=` to the `min` and ending with the last value that is `>=` to the `max`.

```js
foobar(250, 1010) // returns [400, 700, 1000, 1300]
foobar(0, 15) // returns [100]
```

How to implement this using modern JS?

---

```js
array.filter((num) => {
  return num >= min && num <= max
})
```

Always loses the last number.

Comment: You need to show what you tried

Comment: try `array.filter(number => number >= min && number <= max)`.

Comment: @RashadKokash `foobar(250, 1010)` returns `[400, 700, 1000]` 

Comment: @RDN Isn't this right ? if not what is the expected return value?

Comment: @RashadKokash Last value that is `>=` to the `max` (`1010`) is `1300`, not `1000`

Comment: Oh now I understand, after getting the numbers with the code above you can use `array.indexOf` last item in filter return value and get the index after it if it is not the last one.

Comment: @RashadKokash Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case of `for...of` loop.

```
const array = [100, 400, 700, 1000, 1300, 1600];

function foobar(array,min,max) {
    let new_array = [];
    for (let val of array) {
        if(min<=val && val<=max) {
            new_array.push(val);
        } else if(val>max) {
            new_array.push(val);
            break;
        }

    }
    return new_array;
}

console.log(foobar(array,0,15));     // outputs [100]
console.log(foobar(array,250,1010)); // outputs [400, 700, 1000, 1300]
```

It's simple, follows conventional programming paradigm and it traverses the array only once.

Comment: Single iteration over the array is a win here - was about to post similar solution :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

```js
const array = [100, 400, 700, 1000, 1300, 1600];

const foobar = (min, max) => {

    // get the lowest number higher than or equal to max
    const lowestHigh = array.find(n => (n >= max));
    
    const within = val => (val >= min && val <= lowestHigh);
    return array.filter(within);
};

console.log( foobar(0, 150) );
console.log( foobar(400, 1500) );
```

Comment: `foobar(0, 150)` should return `[100, 400]`, `foobar(400, 1500)` should return `[400, 700, 1000, 1300, 1600]` 